# Generate from regular expression with Plumatic Schema generators

Tags: clojure, plumatic-schema

Regexes seem to be accepted schemas:

```
(require '[schema.core :as schema])

(schema/validate #"^..$" "hi") ; => "hi"
```

But schema-generators can't seem to generate from them:

```
(require '[schema-generators.generators :as gen])

(gen/generate #"^..$")
; 1. Unhandled java.lang.RuntimeException
;    You must provide a leaf generator for
;    schema.spec.leaf.LeafSpec@3d398cfd
```

Is it possible to work around this in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use the `miner/strgen` library we can indeed work up a solution:

```
(require '[schema.core  :as schema]
         '[miner.strgen :as strgen]
         '[schema-generators.generators :as gen])

(def two-char #"^..$")
(schema/validate two-char "hi") ; => "hi"

(gen/generate two-char {two-char (strgen/string-generator #"^..$")})
; => "x["
```

Though it should be noted that this only provides a generator for the regex `#"^..$"` in perticular and not regular expressions in general. We need a better solution, perhaps extend some protocol somewhere.